# Read Objects inside Array inside JSON object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

In provided encoded JSON object that stores an array of objects that I want to read the value of Id/factorType/provider.

```
{"factors":{
    "factors":[{
    "id":"reytfufsiwdg",
    "factorType":"email",
    "provider":"ABC",
    "factorsProfile":{
    "email":"a...r@gmail.com"
    }}]}}
```

Comment: `objectVariable.factors.factors[0].id` (or `factorType` or `provider`).

Comment: `const { id, factorType, provider} = obj.factors.factors[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = {"factors":{
    "factors":[{
    "id":"reytfufsiwdg",
    "factorType":"email",
    "provider":"ABC",
    "factorsProfile":{
    "email":"a...r@gmail.com"
    }}]}};
    

    
   for(var key in data){
    for(var innerKey in data[key]){
     for(var innerKey2 in data[key][innerKey]){
        for(var innerKey3 in data[key][innerKey][innerKey2]){
          if(innerKey3 == "factorType" || innerKey3 == "provider"|| innerKey3 == "id")
         console.log(data[key][innerKey][innerKey2][innerKey3])
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

or you can use

```js
var data = {"factors":{
        "factors":[{
        "id":"reytfufsiwdg",
        "factorType":"email",
        "provider":"ABC",
        "factorsProfile":{
        "email":"a...r@gmail.com"
        }}]}};
        


data.factors.factors.forEach(factor => {
  console.log(factor.id)
    console.log(factor.factorType)
      console.log(factor.provider)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
data.factors.factors.forEach(factor => {
    console.log(`ID is: ${factor.id}`)
  console.log(`Type is ${factor.factorType}`)
  console.log(`Provider is: ${factor.provider}`)
})
```

You can even try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/qe4a4Lmg/